# Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor for AZ funcitons isolated

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have many v3 AZ functions which all work fine, but as we're migrating to **v4 isolated** I can no longer run it localy. The error I get is "`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage: Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor`"

I can start azurite separatly before VS 2022, and I can access it using Azure Storage explorer, but it doesn't work from VS 2022 (17.3.6). I've also tried running VS as admin, but the issue remains...

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that I had nested objects in my appsettings.json file.